# How to import `.../` in React?

Tags: reactjs

I want to structure my files. The ideal structure is below:

```
├── src
│   ├── Data
│   │   ├── AppData.js
│   │   └── AppsData.js
│   ├── Components
│   │   └── Main
│   │       └── Main.js
│   ├── Views
│   │   ├── AppList
│   │   ├── Footer.js
│   │   └── Header.js
│   │
...
```

But problem is that if I import Header.js from Main.js, `import Header from '.../Views/Header'` fails. When I import Header from `/Components/Main.js` with `import Header from '../Views/Header'` succeeds.

How to import `.../` files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confused by all the dots here...
`./File.js` means "File.js in current directory"
`../File.js` means "File.js one directory up"
`../../File.js` means "File.js two directories up"

To fix your problem, do following

```
// Components/Main/Main.js
import Header from "../../Views/Header"
```

Comment: Ah... Exactly what you said... I was confused for React.. Anyway thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

You are using [relative path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)#Absolute_and_relative_paths)., and when you do `../Views/Header.js` you are trying find `Header.js` in `Components` folder, but you need move up to `src` folder, so just add additional `..` to your path

```
import Header from '../../Views/Header'
```